# Do I need to apply for a visa to enter to South Korea if I already got Aus visa?

Tags: visas, international-travel, south-korea

I'm currently holding Vietnamese passport and studying in Australia. I read some sources saying that I don't have to apply for visa if I already have a valid Australia visa. Is that true? Or will I be granted a visa on arrival or just buy a ticket and then go?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=VN&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=KR&EM=AU&TR=00&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C#) you may not need to if you don't depart back to Australia when arriving from Australia.

> **Visa required, except for Holders of a visa issued by
>   Australia, Canada, Japan, New Zealand or USA** to nationals of
>   Viet Nam, only if in transit through Korea (Rep.):
>
> For details, click here

**CLARIFICATION**

> Visa Exemptions:
>
> - Holders of a visa issued by Australia, Canada, Japan, New
>     Zealand or USA to nationals of any country except for Cuba,
>     Iran, Macedonia (FYROM), Sudan and Syria, only if in transit
>     through Korea (Rep.):
> - holding confirmed onward tickets on flights departing
>     within 30 days; when
> - arriving from a third country, departing to the country
>     that issued the visa (e.g. DEL-ICN-YVR); or
> - arriving on a direct flight from the country that issued
>     the visa (a visa that expired on departure from that country
>     is accepted), departing to a third country (e.g.
>     YVR-ICN-DEL).
>
>   Not applicable to holders a group visa issued by Japan or an
>     e-visa.
>
>   Not applicable if traveling from/to Guam or Northern Mariana
>     Isl.

**END CLARIFICATION**

> Visa required, except for A max. stay of 30 days for nationals
>   of Viet Nam traveling as tourist, if arriving at and departing
>   from Jeju (CJU) and For details, click here
>
> Visa required, except for Holders of an APEC Business Travel
>   Card (ABTC)For details, click here provided endorsed  Valid for travel
>   to KOR".
>
> Visa required, except for Those who have previously entered
>   Korea (Rep.) at least 4 times within the last 2 years, or at
>   least 10 visits in total.
>
> Additional Information:
>
> - Nationals of Viet Nam traveling as a group on business or as
>     a group of school children can be issued with a Group Visa.
> - Holders of e-visas are required to hold an Electronic Visa
>     Issuance Confirmation, issued by the Ministry of Justice.
> - Visitors are required to hold proof of sufficient funds to
>     cover their stay and documents required for their next
>     destination.
>
> Warning:
>
> - Passport number and nationality must match those stated on
>     the APEC Business Travel Card (ABTC).

Long story short you will need a visa for a trip: (Australia) -> Korea -> (Australia) otherwise if you add Viet Nam into the trip either as a source or as a destination you may not need a visa if departure from Korea is within 30 days of your arrival.

Comment: Does that just mean you don't need a visa if you're in transit, or you don't need one to visit? I read it as the former, and the question isn't clear on whether a transit or a visit is planned.

Comment: @KateGregory The way I read it is that if the trip is 30 days or less and 1 and only 1 of the end points of the trip is the Country that issued a visa then visa is not required.