# Visa-free travel to South Korea for Filipino citizens holding an Australian visa

Tags: visas, south-korea, filipino-citizens

I've heard that you can travel to South Korea without a visa if you have an Australian visa and your flight is bound to/from that country. I plan to do this to travel from the Philippines to South Korea (flying on Korean Air) and my final destination will be Australia. Will it work?

I'm a citizen of the Philippines.

I've found a [link](http://www.hikorea.go.kr/pt/InfoDetailR_en.pt?categoryId=2&parentId=385&catSeq=401&show) on Korea's official government website (Transit tourists bound for another country section) but not sure if you have from & to travel these 5 countries.

Comment: To clarify, you're a Filipino? (passport?)

Comment: Yes, i hold philipines passport

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47099/do-i-need-to-apply-for-a-visa-to-enter-to-south-korea-if-i-already-got-aus-visa/47102#47102

Comment: @kwan245 Do you plan to stay in Korea or just transit through?

Comment: Stay for few days

Comment: Thanks Karlson but i am not sure you have to from & to or you can just from or to. Thx

Comment: What about this line in the linked question "arriving from a third country, departing to the country that issued the visa (e.g. DEL-ICN-YVR)"

Comment: i plan to depart from Philipines which my passport country so not sure if it can be categorized as 3rd country.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can travel to South Korea visa free, according to the [official website for foreigners in Korea](http://www.hikorea.go.kr/pt/InfoDetailR_en.pt?categoryId=2&parentId=385&catSeq=401&show), as long as:

1. You're not a citizen of Macedonia, Cuba, Syria, Sudan or Iran
2. You're holding a valid visa for Australia in the form of a physical sticker (e-visas are excluded)
3. You are traveling **to Australia** from **any** country **OR** traveling **from Australia** to **any** country
4. You have a confirmed ticket to Australia departing within 30 calendar days of entering South Korea **OR** you have a valid ticket to any country outside of South Korea, if arriving directly from Australia
5. You have no record of criminal offence in any of the five countries (U.S., Japan, Canada, Australia, New Zealand)